# TCPDF Some characters cannot be seen

Tags: php, tcpdf

I am not able to see some of the characters, generated by TCPDF.

**php file:**

```
<?php
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'cp1254', false);
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', ' ', 10);
$pdf->Write(0, 'helloşüğı');
$pdf->Output('hello_world.pdf');
?>
```

Output is this : **hello**

By the way i am using dejavusans fonts, which supports my alphabet's characters. (Turkish)

Answer (score 1):

Set the `$unicode` parameter on the TCPDF constructor to false and the $encoding parameter to `'ISO-8859-1'` or some other character map.

Example of constructor for European charset:

```
 $pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT,
        false, 'ISO-8859-1', false);
```

Try with this.

Comment: Now I get this as the output : 硣穸挀ثىسي竾

Comment: google the exact utf format of that language..use that and it will work

Comment: my format is ISO-8859-9. With $unicode=false i get 硣穸挀ثىسي竾 characters. With $unicode=true i get hello.

Answer (score 0):

i solved the same problem with the following usage

```
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, 

PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);
$pdf->setFontSubsetting(true);
// font for turkish characters ex: ş, ç, ı, ğ, ü, ö
$pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 10, '', true);
```